# choosing two numbers $x_1,x_2$ out of $\{1 \dots n\}$ what is the probability that $x_1<x_2$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given that the two selections are independent:

**My solution** is quite combinatoric.

The sample space $\Omega $ is all possible selections, thus : $|\Omega| = n(n-1)$

The number of ways to choose two numbers such that $x_1<x_2$ is the number of ways to choose a set $X\subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}$ such that $|X| =2$, since after $X$ is chosen there is only one way to organize $x_1,x_2$ such that $x_1<x_2$.

This gives a final result of $\frac{\binom{n}{2}}{n(n-1)} = \frac{1}{2}$

According to the **text book** the final solution is $\frac{n-1}{2n}$

I can't seem to find my mistake.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

It seems like they meant in the text book that $|\Omega| = n^2$ , means it is possible to choose the same number. Than my answer would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You did not pick $x_1$ and $x_2$ independently by disallowing $x_1=x_2$. One might argue that that "pick two numbers" is ambiguous enough to be interpreted as "pick two *distinct* numbers", but actually one should explicitly mention distinctness if it is desired.

Comment: Thanks, just noticed it as well :)

Answer (score 1):

There are $n^2$ ways to choose $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ and total $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ways to choose two distinct numbers. Thus required probability  $$\frac{\binom{n}{2}}{n^{2}}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^{2}}=\frac{(n-1)}{2n}$$.Done.Hope it helps.